# Is a topology always an initial topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let me clarify my question; and it may turn out to be trivially obvious, but I just can't see it. Given two sets $A \xrightarrow{f} B$, for which there exists a surjective map $f$; this is just to ensure that $A \geq B$, so to speak. Now equip $A$ and $B$ with topologies: $(A,\tau_A)$ and $(B,\tau_B)$. My question is: Will there always exist a map $A \xrightarrow{\phi} B$ so $\tau_A = \mathcal{T}(\phi)$, the initial topology? I suspect not, but under what conditions will it exist?

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\{\bullet\}$ (a one-point set). Then there is only one function $\phi : A \rightarrow B$ (defined by $\forall n \in A : \phi(n) = \bullet$) and only one topology on $B$, but at least countable number of topologies on $A$.

Comment: It's not ever true when $B$ is finite and $|A|>|B|$, because there can only be $2^{|B|}$ open sets for $B$ and thus for the initial topology, but the discrete topology on $A$ has $2^{|A|}$ open sets. More generally, if $2^{|B|}<2^{|A|}$, it can't be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is *very* rarely true.  For instance, if $\tau_A$ is a $T_0$ topology, then any $\phi$ for which it is the initial topology must be an injection (since if $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, then the open sets containing $x$ and $y$ are the same in the initial topology).  It follows that if $\tau_A$ is $T_0$, then such a $\phi$ exists iff $(A,\tau_A)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $(B,\tau_B)$.